# Windows server - moving to new server with AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, users, copying

I want to add/copy users on new server with AD from server without AD ( Windows 2012). What is recoomended scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd379531(v=ws.10) for the documentation on how to migrate local users and groups with Windows Server Migration Tools. The destination server will be a DC which will create the users as domain users.